# How to project the two-mode network(bipartite) into one-mode networks using Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, networkx, social-networking

I created bipartite network by reading 5 million record from CSV file. Now, I'm trying to convert this two-mode network to one mode network.
Please help how to achieve this task.
I used pandas and matpoltib library for plotting bipartite network in Python.

Comment: You have not given many details or code, but I would recommend to take a look at [`networkx`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/index.html) (probably accidentally tagged) and especially the [Bipartite Module](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/bipartite.html), which also contains functions for projections.

Comment: Ipos = nx.bipartite_layout(B, left)

I used  networkx library to draw bipartite network. I'm wondering how to convert it into one mode network.

Comment: Take a look at the [projections](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/bipartite.html#module-networkx.algorithms.bipartite.projection).

Comment: Thank you I was able to solve problem using projections in networkx documentation.

Comment: You can create an answer to your own question and post the code, which helped to resolve your issue. Since I don't exactly your needs, I could only point you to the right points in the documentation. But your solution would help others with similar problems ;)